# Comparing counts in rows from a Dataframe with Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, row

I'm trying to obtain the most common asnwers so we have Yes/No questions and it has i eleven questions from this one I would like to know from Yes/No which was has most answers as an example:

If in more than the half of the eleven i's has No>Yes the most common answers will be 'NO' but I'm not really sure what function I need to do this, comparing the rows 0 and 1 to know which one had more answers.

I would like to do this kind of script:

if row[0] > row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go3lT.png):
print("No is the most common answer")

This is the example data that I have:

```
  index i1  i2  i3  i4  i5  i6      i7      i8  i9  i10 i11 
0   No  94  123 96  108 122 106.0   95.0    124 104 118 73  
1   Yes 34  4   33  21  5   25.0    34.0    5   21  9   55
```

EDIT:
Wanted result for using just the first column.

[image]

Comment: As a starting point, you could use the result of `df.loc[0]>df.loc[1]`, which should be a series of `True` or `False` values.

Comment: Hello friendo would you mind showing us your wanted result that would help us a lot?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 at the end of the post you will find the wanted result. I want that using df.loc[0]>df.loc[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a list of 'yes' and 'no' you can do:

```
no_count = df.iloc[0].values[1:]
yes_count = df.iloc[1].values[1:]
most_common = ['no' if no_count[i]>yes_count[i] else 'yes' for i in range(len(no_count))]
```

Then you can count the number of each

```
number_no = most_common.count("no")
number_yes = most_common.count("yes")
```

Comment: I really like this answer now with the list how can I make to count and compare from the list the most repited result?

Comment: Answer edited above :)